# InnoDB - Intermittent CPU spikes on a large database

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6

I have a machine with a large MySQL 5.6 database (multiple tables with 10-100 million rows). It has a considerable amount of load, especially during the evening and is running on a 16 core machine.

No matter what the load is though, we always get these intermittent spikes that can cause problems. Our CPU load looks like this:

[image: CPU Load]

(these are very load-light times, especially the time before 6am, should be basically "idle")

The only solution to the problem I have found so far is setting up a new server, mirroring the data and switching to that one. This usually buys me about 2-3 months, then the spikes start appearing again. Just restarting MySQL or rebooting the server does not change anything.

These are also not caused by cronjobs. Even if I disable all of them, this still happens.

Here is a gist of the InnoDB status right now:

https://gist.github.com/fleshgolem/de1d4a661fb545fabfda

And here is a dump of the server variables:

```
Variable_name   Value
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
back_log    200
basedir /usr
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    *
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_format   ROW
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
block_encryption_mode   aes-128-ecb
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir /var/lib/mysql/
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    ON
eq_range_index_dive_limit   10
error_count 0
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp OFF
external_user   
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file    /var/lib/mysql/xxxx.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed   
gtid_mode   ON
gtid_next   AUTOMATIC
gtid_owned  
gtid_purged 
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  YES
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    DISABLED
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    DISABLED
have_symlink    DISABLED
host_cache_size 640
hostname    xxxx
identity    0
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 42949672960
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   innodb
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  2
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors  0
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON
innodb_log_file_size    104857600
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   2000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_threads    1
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  16
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_status_output    OFF
innodb_status_output_locks  OFF
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_undo_directory   .
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  5.6.19
innodb_write_io_threads 16
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 8388608
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir /usr/share/mysql/
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
locked_in_memory    OFF
log_bin ON
log_bin_basename    /var/lib/mysql/xxxx-db1-bin
log_bin_index   /var/lib/mysql/xxxx-db1-bin.index
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_error   /var/log/mysqld.log
log_output  FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   ON
log_slow_admin_statements   OFF
log_slow_slave_statements   OFF
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_warnings    1
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  OFF
lower_case_table_names  0
master_info_repository  TABLE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  4194304
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 750
max_delayed_threads 20
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   18446744073709551615
max_sort_length 1024a
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    5000
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
performance_schema  ON
performance_schema_accounts_size    100
performance_schema_digests_size 10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10
performance_schema_hosts_size   100
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   5900
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   7693
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  19500
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   40
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances 10300
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances 1520
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    168
performance_schema_max_table_handles    4000
performance_schema_max_table_instances  12500
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances 1600
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    100
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   100
performance_schema_users_size   100
pid_file    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin_dir  /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/
port    3306
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
proxy_user  
pseudo_slave_mode   OFF
pseudo_thread_id    2018
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    1048576000
query_cache_type    ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
rand_seed1  0
rand_seed2  0
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_buffer_size    131072
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144
relay_log   
relay_log_basename  
relay_log_index 
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   TABLE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host 10.129.156.251
report_password 
report_port 3306
report_user 
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv    
server_id   1
server_id_bits  32
server_uuid 96bcdb70-44c5-11e5-8df9-0401654ee301
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   /tmp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   3600
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   ALL
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file /var/lib/mysql/xxxx-slow.log
socket  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca  
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert    
ssl_cipher  
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key 
storage_engine  InnoDB
stored_program_cache    256
sync_binlog 0
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    1
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    EST
table_definition_cache  1400
table_open_cache    2000
table_open_cache_instances  1
thread_cache_size   15
thread_concurrency  10
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   SYSTEM
timed_mutexes   OFF
timestamp   1457343545.452900
tmp_table_size  16777216
tmpdir  /tmp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_allow_batching  OFF
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.6.19-log
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Linux
wait_timeout    28800
warning_count   0
```

If there is any more relevant info you need, please let me know and I will update the question accordingly. I unfortunately have no clue anymore what I am looking for.

Comment: [The only solution to the problem I have found so far is setting up a new server, mirroring the data and switching to that one. This usually buys me about 2-3 months, then the spikes start appearing again.] - if translate to other words, You not migrate data, You defragment them. Did You do some time ANALYSE TABLE or OPTIMISE TABLE on Your servers?

Comment: No, I did not and right now I am wary about running them on a production server. Will those cause problems/lock the tables for prolonged periods?

In the case of ANALYZE, what should I look out for?

Comment: Yes, on a big tables - it always slowdown and downtime during the operation. But on frequent update tables (and as I understand it is a game server) - no other choices. as much more and often You are update data - as much slower (more work for permanent re-order indexes). My practice work on similar problem projects show - VERY often, 80 % of this 100 millions rows - don't needed history. Think about split tables for operative and history - control the data, but not data control You, define planned downtime for defragment/optimise data once per 2 month ...

Comment: How much RAM?  Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` also.

Comment: Set `long_query_time=1` and turn on the slow log.  Wait a day, then summarize with `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest`.  That will provide one or two queries to focus in on.

Comment: It is a very intersting graph.  It is as if it periodically precomputes some stuff, then is relatively idle for some time before needing to do it again.

Comment: @RickJames 50GB, global status is here: https://gist.github.com/fleshgolem/fcbca1aaff62f39078f4, and nothing appears in the slow log whatsoever during that period (or otherwise for that matter)

Comment: I'll study the `STATUS` later.  `long_query_time 10.000000` excludes a lot of interesting queries.

Comment: I added the `STATUS` analysis to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably it:

```
query_cache_size    1048576000
query_cache_type    ON
```

What is happening:  a write comes in, the entire GB of QC needs to be scanned to find all instances of that table to purge them.  That takes a lot of CPU time.  Meanwhile, *all* `SELECTs` are blocked.

Do not set the size bigger than about 50M, regardless of how much RAM you have.  It would probably be wise to also use `DYNAMIC` instead of `ON`, and hand-pick which `SELECTs` to have `SQL_CACHE` and which to have `SQL_NO_CACHE`.

Or it may be that the QC is not worth having on at all.  This is the common case for Production systems that have constant write traffic.

More...

**Based on VARIABLES and GLOBAL STATUS**

**Observations:**

Version: 5.6.19-log
50 GB of RAM
Uptime = 11d 07:07:58
You are not running on Windows.
Running 64-bit version
It appears that you are running both MyISAM and InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues**

Either convert completely to InnoDB or tweak the cache sizes.  SUggest

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 30G -- you are not using all of the 40G now
key_buffer_size = 2G -- your current 8M is not efficient for writes
```

query_cache_size is really bad at 1000M.  Your usage is *moderately* effective, so consider:

- Add `SQL_CACHE` or `SQL_NO_CACHE` to all `SELECTs, based on which ones are likely to benefit,
- Decrease `query_cach_size` to only `100m`

A lot of queries are using tmp tables and, worse, disk tmp tables.  Using the slowlog, find out which queries are the most invasive; let's work on them.

Raise `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` from 16M to 32M (but no more).  Since there are two ways that tmp tables can turn into 'disk tmp tables', this *might* prevent some conversions.

`slave_skip_errors = ALL` -- Sweeping problems under the rug.  Big time!

**Details and other observations**

( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 1,864,255 * 16384 / 42949672960 = 71.1% -- buffer pool free
-- buffer_pool_size is bigger than working set; could decrease it

( Innodb_log_writes ) = 40,597,718 / 976078 = 42 /sec

( Com_rollback ) = 99,316,489 / 976078 = 101 /sec -- ROLLBACKs in InnoDB.
-- An excessive frequency of rollbacks may indicate inefficient app logic.

( local_infile ) = ON
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

( Key_writes / Key_write_requests ) = 2,200,386 / 4113735 = 53.5% -- key_buffer effectiveness for writes
-- If you have enough RAM, it would be worthwhile to increase key_buffer_size.

( query_cache_size ) = 1000M -- Size of QC
-- Too small = not of much use. Too large = too much overhead. Recommend either 0 or no more than 50M.

( Qcache_not_cached ) = 235,136,200 / 976078 = 240 /sec -- SQL_CACHE attempted, but ignored
-- Rethink caching; tune qcache

( Qcache_inserts - Qcache_queries_in_cache ) = (258097280 - 7736) / 976078 = 264 /sec -- Invalidations/sec.

( (query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size ) = (1000M - 11519952) / 7736 / 8192 = 16.4 -- query_alloc_block_size vs formula
-- Adjust query_alloc_block_size

( Created_tmp_tables ) = 31,198,441 / 976078 = 32 /sec -- Frequency of creating "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs.

( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 5,996,371 / 976078 = 6.1 /sec -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size.
Check the rules for temp tables being able to use MEMORY instead of MyISAM. It may be possible to make a minor schema or query change to avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

( Handler_read_rnd_next ) = 1,066,165,445,800 / 976078 = 1092295 /sec -- High if lots of table scans
-- possibly inadequate keys

( Com_rollback / Com_commit ) = 99,316,489 / 49548802 = 200.4% -- Rollback : Commit ratio
-- Rollbacks are costly; change app logic

( Select_scan ) = 16,213,392 / 976078 = 17 /sec -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (57757683 + 26581027 + 0 + 0 + 34482709 + 0) / 976078 = 121 /sec -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives

( expire_logs_days ) = 0 -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin = OFF)

( slow_query_log ) = OFF -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

( long_query_time ) = 10.000000 = 10 -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

( Aborted_clients / Connections ) = 33,444 / 45497 = 73.5% -- Threads bumped due to timeout
-- Increase wait_timeout; be nice, use disconnect

( Threads_created / Connections ) = 3,675 / 45497 = 8.1% -- Rapidity of process creation
-- Increase thread_cache_size

innodb_log_file_size is small (but hard to change).

Good caching in buffer_pool.

Good caching of table_definitions.

Com_delete = 27/sec

Any swapping?

GTID -- is this Master?